# Compare two array elements using if() statment

Tags: javascript

Code bellow works fine, though as u can see, everything is hand wrote and if i want to push something to that arrays i will have to change whole code.
working example:

```
for (var s = 0; s < myButtons.length; s++) {
    if (
        (myButtons[s].className == "1" && colorIndex[0] > 1)
        ||
        (myButtons[s].className == "2" && colorIndex[1] > 1)
        ||
        (myButtons[s].className == "3" && colorIndex[2] > 1)
        ||
        (myButtons[s].className == "4" && colorIndex[3] > 1)
        ||
        (myButtons[s].className == "5" && colorIndex[4] > 1)
        ||
        (myButtons[s].className == "6" && colorIndex[5] > 1)
    ) {continue;}
    alert("things need to be done")
}
```

the best solution came to my mind(not working one):

```
for (var s = 0; s < myButtons.length; s++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < colorIndex.length; i++) {
        if ((myButtons[s].className == (i + 1) && colorIndex[i] > 1)) {
            continue;
        }
        alert("things need to be done")
    }
}
```

So what i want is: to check if all elements of array myButtons.classname==variable from cycle && colorIndex[variable from cycle]>1 OR same thing again but on next step

working code for the first algorithm

```js
const colorIndex = []
  colorIndex[0]  = 201
  colorIndex[1]  = 30002
  colorIndex[19] = -25
  colorIndex[3]  = 89
  colorIndex[-7] = 89
  colorIndex[-9] = -26

const myButtons = [...document.querySelectorAll("button")] 

for (var s = 0; s < myButtons.length; s++)
  {
  if ( (myButtons[s].className == "1" && colorIndex[0] > 1)
    || (myButtons[s].className == "2" && colorIndex[1] > 1)
    || (myButtons[s].className == "3" && colorIndex[2] > 1)
    || (myButtons[s].className == "4" && colorIndex[3] > 1)
    || (myButtons[s].className == "5" && colorIndex[4] > 1)
    || (myButtons[s].className == "6" && colorIndex[5] > 1)
    )
    { continue }
  alert("things need to be done")
  }
  
console.log('test ending')
```

```html
<button class="1">1</button>
<button class="2">2</button>
<button class="4">3</button>
<button class="4">4</button>
<button class="4">5</button>
<button class="4">6</button>
<button class="4">7</button>
<button class="2">8</button>
<button class="4">9</button>
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: How to make code automatic, when i will push in arr color.Index new element, now i will have to change if() structure, i want do code did that for me

Comment: I guess i am doing something wrong about this question, i do not understand why i am getting downvoted???

Comment: @flemethwow I haven't down-voted but I assume it is because the question isn't very clear about what it is that you are asking, but I don't think its down-vote worthy. You showed your code and a proposed solution but you it just isn't very clear what the problem is. You could have added something like *How can I make the first script more generic*. It's also a good idea to provide a small example that can recreate your code (in this case we don't know what `myButtons` and `colorIndex`, though it sounds like that they are arrays of elements and numbers respectively).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a pretty short and less hard coded version of the original code

```js
var myButtons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var colorIndex = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1];

for (var index = 0; index < myButtons.length; index++) {
  if (myButtons[index].className == String(index + 1) 
 && colorIndex[myButtons[index].className - 1] > 1) continue;
  console.log("Button at index '" + index + "' needs to get fixed");
}
```

```html
<button class="1">1</button>
<button class="2">2</button>
<button class="3">3</button>
<button class="4">4</button>
<button class="5">5</button>
<button class="6">6</button>
```

Full code attempt:

```js
// Create Buttons Start


var buttonDom = document.getElementById("a1");
var buttonList = [],
  buttonCount = 12;
while (buttonList.length < buttonCount) {
  var newInput = document.createElement("input");
  newInput.type = "button";
  buttonList.push(newInput);
  buttonDom.appendChild(newInput);
}

var randomList1 = [];
while (randomList1.length < buttonCount / 2) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * buttonCount / 2) + 1;
  if (randomList1.indexOf(random) === -1) randomList1.push(random);
}

var randomList2 = [];
while (randomList2.length < buttonCount / 2) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * buttonCount / 2) + 1;
  if (randomList2.indexOf(random) === -1) randomList2.push(random);
}

randomList1.forEach((random, index) => buttonList[index].setAttribute("class", random));
randomList2.forEach((random, index) => buttonList[index + buttonCount / 2].setAttribute("class", random));

// Game Start

var myButtons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']");
var click = 1;
var colorIndex = "0".repeat(6).split("").map(Number);
var color = ["red", "blue", "green", "black", "gold", "grey"];
myButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", game));

function clickTrun() {
  click = !click | 0;
}

function win() {
  if (colorIndex.every(i => i == 2)) {
    alert("YOU WON mdfker!");
    location.reload();
  }
}

function resetColorIndex() {
  if (click === 1) {
    colorIndex = colorIndex.map(function(colorValue) {
      return colorValue < 2 ? 0 : colorValue;
    });
  }
}

function mainGameRules() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resetColorIndex();
    if (click === 1) {
      myButtons.forEach(function(button) {
        if (colorIndex[button.className - 1] > 1) return;
        button.setAttribute("style", "background-color: none;");
        button.disabled = false;
      });
    }
  }, 700);
}

function game() {
  this.disabled = true;
  var index = this.className - 1;
  if (index in colorIndex) {
    this.setAttribute("style", "background-color:" + color[index]);
    colorIndex[index]++;
    mainGameRules();
    clickTrun();
  }
  win();
}
```

```html
<div id="a1">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to formulate what you want to do and express it in code. Without sticking to concrete index, try to figure out how any possible index corresponds to particular color. Looking at your example you want to take className for every button, subtract 1 and take color from colorIndex and do something if that color is less than or equal to 1

```
for (let i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++) {
  // className for current button
  const className = myButtons[i].className
  // parse it into number
  const num = Number(className)
  // if number is valid, take element from colorIndex at number-1 position
  // and see if that's not bigger than 1
  if (num && colorIndex[num - 1] <= 1) {
    console.log('things need to be done for index ' + i)
  }
}
```

but my suggestion would be to reconsider your existing setup with myButtons and colorIndex into something more sophisticated